# How to add keyboard shortcut for Tomboy 'create new note'?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on Linux Mint and I use Tomboy Notes a lot. I want to add a custom keyboard shortcut to instantly open a 'new note' window and start typing. I've already created a custom keyboard shortcut for Tomboy but that basically launches the main search window rather than creating a new note for me to start typing immediately. Is there a way I can achieve that?

I've searched online and found different commands for Tomboy e.g. 'tomboy --search' but not for instant note creation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I've managed to work it out and since there are no other answers yet, I thought I might as well post my solution here in case anyone else is interested.

So basically, in the "Add custom shortcut" command section I had to type "tomboy --new-note" rather than just "tomboy".

If you are not aware of certain command options supported by a program, you can simply type in your terminal "[program name] --help" and it will list them all out for you.

```
user@laptop:~$ tomboy --help
Tomboy: A simple, easy to use desktop note-taking application.
Copyright © 2004-2007 Alex Graveley
<alex@beatniksoftware.com>

Copyright © 2004-2017 Others
Usage:
  --version         Print version information.
  --help            Print this usage message.
  --note-path [path]        Load/store note data in this directory.
  --search [text]       Open the search all notes window with the search text.
  --new-note            Create and display a new note.
  --new-note [title]        Create and display a new note, with a title.
  --open-note [title/url]   Display the existing note matching title.
  --start-here          Display the 'Start Here' note.
  --highlight-search [text] Search and highlight text in the opened note.
  --addin:html-export-all [path]    Exports all notes to HTML in the given location.
  --addin:html-export-all-quit [path]   Exports all notes to HTML in the given location and then quits.
```